# Datastore v1Beta2 to v1 API incompatibilities

Tags: api, migration, google-cloud-datastore

I'm having significant issues migrating our Java code (written for the v1Beta2 Datastore API) to conform to the v1 API. Here are the mismatches:

1. Value Class: What happened to hasDoubleValue(), hasStringValue(), and other functions that let you determine the type of value stored? What's the new way to determine the value type?
2. What happened to all the getBuilder() methods associated with LookupRequest, Query, RunQueryRequest, ...? Do we now simply call the constructors for those classes? The Builder class and getBuilder() method seemed needlessly convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the value type, you can use a switch statement:

```
switch (value.getValueTypeCase()) {
  case DOUBLE_VALUE:
    value.getDoubleValue()...
    break;
  case STRING_VALUE:
    value.getStringValue()...
    break;
  ...
}
```

To get a `LookupRequest.Builder` object, you can call `LookupRequest.newBuilder()` (same for other message types).

By the way, if you are rewriting code to stop using Cloud Datastore v1beta2, you may want to check out [google-cloud-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java) which provides a more idiomatic wrapper for the protocol buffers API.

Comment: Value.getValueTypeCase() does not appear to be documented in https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/datastore/v1/java/latest/. Similarly, I don't see the newBuilder() method documented. Am I looking in the correct place for the documentation on the various Datastore classes?  For the .Builder classes, I think you are confirming that they still exist.

Comment: Ah, I think we are talking about different libraries. Which library were you  using and which one are you switching to?

Comment: I'm totally confused about the notion of libraries. I thought there's one API library for Java clients running on Compute Engines. If there are two, let me know what they are and which one to use so that all the Builder classes are described. I'm counting on them. I'm also not using Maven or Gradle, but instead I directly use the javac compiler. So I also need to know where to pick up all the necessary JAR files to get the code built. My goal is to preserve as much of the v2Beta version code and try to get it to work for v1. Thanks.

Comment: If you were starting from scratch, I'd recommend [google-cloud-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java). Since it sounds like you're not, you're probably either using [google-cloud-datastore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore) or [Google APIs Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/). v1beta2 is not compatible with v1, so there will be some code changes either way.

Comment: Correct. I have v1beta2 code that I need to get up and running. I'm willing to make the changes, but only those that are absolutey necessary. So can you point me to the full documentation for Java Classes (similar to Javadoc https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/datastore/v1/java/latest/) that clears up the mystery of the missing methods (like Value.getValueTypeCase()). I'll upvote once I have the correct link. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like you were using [google-cloud-datastore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore). The Javadocs for that library are not hosted anywhere, but you can download the javadoc.jar files from Maven [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22datastore-v1-proto-client%22) and [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22datastore-v1-protos%22).

Comment: The two links you provided to the javadoc.jar files were a HUGE help! These should definitely be made accessible through the Cloud Console. I was able to access documentation for most classes except for  com.google.api.Property? Any idea where that might be?

Comment: I was able to locate the Javadocs for com.google.api.Property.Builder. So please ignore the previous comment. The issue now is that setValue() method no longer exists, and I can't seem to find an alternate method from the Javadocs description for the Property.Builder class. Any suggestions? Thanks.